# SQL Server Dynamic SQL "Quote hell" with OPENDATASOURCE

Tags: excel, quotes, dynamic-sql

I want to build a parameterized SQL Query that retrieves data from an Excel file.

The name of the Excel file will change every year.

Here is the query that runs fine in T-SQL (on SQL Server 2008 R2 Express):

```
SELECT * INTO MobilityData FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=\\UNCPath\Annual_Mobility_Update\DAM2013-3.xls;Extended Properties=Excel  8.0')...
[Sheet1$]
```

go

(UNC Path is a network UNC Path, works fine)

The string 'DAM2013-3.xls' will be changing year on year. What I'd like to do would be execute a parametized stored procedure and build the Dyanamic SQL on the fly...

Something like this:

```
SELECT @sQry='SELECT * INTO MobilityData FROM OPENDATASOURCE(''''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Data Source=\\sgstore\Shared\operations\DM\Annual_Mobility_Update\''' 
+ @XLFileSource + ';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0'')...[Sheet1$]'
```

but I seem to be in quote hell and can't get it to compile.

What should I do to fix this?

I'd be grateful for any tips, fishing rods, or even whole a fish etc

Thanks
Philip

Comment: nope, sorry, I mean that I can't get the number of quotes right in my SQL Query string

Answer (score 1):

here is the fixed code. Hope this help

```
SELECT @sQry='SELECT * INTO MobilityData FROM OPENDATASOURCE(''''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',''Data Source=\\sgstore\Shared\operations\DM\Annual_Mobility_Update\''' 
+ @XLFileSource + ';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0'')...[Sheet1$]'
```